# How to turn off Pydev indentation warnings for certain .py files

Tags: warnings, pydev, indentation

I have some files in my project that are from an external source and that I never edit but sometimes step through.  These files use a different indentation style from my default one (2 spaces vs. 4 spaces), and I currently many indentation warnings on them.  Is there an easy way to suppress these warnings (or alternatively, specify an indentation style) on a file by file basis?  I would expect to be able to solve my problem with the equivalent of a pragma line that I add at the top of the file but so far I haven't found such a thing.  (BTW I would rather not turn off indentation warnings altogether, as I find them useful when editing code.)

Answer (score 5):

You can add #@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore to the beginning of your file to have PyDev skip its code-analysis of that file -- including the indentation warnings (i.e.: go to the top of your file and do Ctrl+1 and such an option will be shown to you).