# Pydev indentation warning in Eclipse

Tags: python, pydev

I am using PyDev perspective. I get a `bad indentation` warning in python files. 
I just copy code from somewhere else, I cannot make sure how much space others use... so how to automatically format that or how to erase that warning? It looks bad.

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093519/eclipse-bad-indentation-warning and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101787/how-to-turn-off-pydev-indentation-warnings-for-certain-py-files

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'automatic' way for that... But usually in this situation you can just do a find/replace from 2 spaces to 3 spaces (or whatever was the format you had to the expected format).

Sometimes rectangular editing is helpful there too (hint: use alt+shift+A to enter/leave rectangular editing mode).